# Displaying a win condition

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a 2d game and I want to display a winning text, every time I reach the bottom of the screen(which is how I win the game) the game just freezes and doesn't show my text. It will although reset and go back to the beginning like I want

```
#this is where I set up my text and font

# def text_objects(text, font):
   # textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
   # return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

#def message_dissplay(text):
  #  largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
   # TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
   # TextRect.center = ((SCREEN_WIDTH/2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
   # gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    #time.sleep(2)

   # main()

#def GameWon():
 #   message_dissplay("You Won")

  #this is the mainloop I use for my game
#def main():
   # pygame.init()

    # Set the height and width of the screen
   # size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
   # screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


    # Main Loop
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

          #I set up my code so if the player reached 750 pixles he gets 
           #reset to 
           #the top and 

         #I want it to display a win text

        if player.rect.y > 750:
            GameWon()
```

I'm really just confused how to add text to my game whenever I meet   a win condition

Comment: always add tag `python` and it will highlight code - it makes it more readable.

Comment: inside `GameWon()` you `sleep()` so it doesn't run `for event` and it can't get information about pressed button or mouse moves - and it can look like freeze. It also doesn't run `pygame.display.update()` which sends image from buffer to monitor (video card which display it). `blit()`, `draw()` doesn't send directly to monitor but to buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`draw()` `blit()` only sends to buffer. You forgot `pygame.screen.update()` or `pygame.screen.flip()` to send graphics from buffer to video card which will display it.

You `GameWon()` use `sleep()` so game can't run `for event` loop and get mouse move/click or pressed key. It also can't run `pygame.screen.update()` to send graphics on screen - and then it looks like it freeze.

In example I use `state` to run different code in main loop - intro, game, gameover, etc. I also use timer to control instead of `sleep` so it doesn't stop loop.

Instead of runing `main()` again I use external `loop` so game can exit old loop, reset settings and run old loop again. This way I don't have to run main() again.

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_dissplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((SCREEN_WIDTH/2), (SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
    #TextRect.center = screen.get_rect().center
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    # Set the height and width of the screen
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    # Main Loop
    repeate_game = True:

    while repeate_game:

        reset_game() # set default values again
        state = 'game' #'intro'

        done = False
        while not done:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True

            current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if state = 'intro'
                # here code for intro

            elif state = 'game'
                # here code for game

                if player.rect.y > 750:
                    state = 'gameover'
                    state_end = current_time + 2000 #2000ms = 2s

            elif state = 'pause'
                # here code for pause

                message_dissplay("Pause")

            elif state = 'gameover'
                # here code for Game Over

                message_dissplay("You Won")

                if current_time > state_end:
                    done = True # to exit `while done` after 2000 ms

            # send buffer to video card and on screen 
            pygame.screen.flip() # or pygame.screen.update()
```